# How do I prove that there is a recurrence?

Tags: algorithm, recurrence, proof

I have the following harmonic sequence:

```
h(n) = 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 +...+ 1/n
```

Id like to prove that there's a recurrence with

```
h(n) (less than or equal to) h( lowerbound( n/2)) + 1
```

Comment: Are you assuming that h(n) <= h(floor(n/2)) + 1 and trying to use that to construct a recurrence, or trying to prove h(n) <= h(floor(n/2)) + 1 ?

Answer (score 1):

This belongs on math.SE, but we have

```
h(2n) - h(n) = 1/(n/2 + 1) + 1/(n/2 + 2) + ... + 1/n
             < 1/(n/2) + 1/(n/2) + ... + 1/(n/2)
             = 1,
```

since there are `n/2` terms. I'll leave the odd case as an exercise.